# proper grounding at main service drop panel

Tags: electrical-panel

If I go from inside my 200 amp semi-flush mount main breaker panel down inside wall and connect to rebar in foundation then from rebar to my water pipe do I still need to use a grounding rod or not? its all new foundation. new construction.

Comment: What are you trying to save here by asking this? Why not just get a proper grounding rod and stick it into the ground? It is not like it is going to break the bank. Online the orange big box store lists 8 foot copper clad grounding bars in the range of 10 to 12 bucks!! Amazon shows them at about 20 bucks.

Comment: In new construction they now regularly add a "Ufer" ground but the re-rod is turned up through the basement floor or slab inside the house near the panel. So, it is more convenient to run the grounding electrode conductor to the panel from there. It's not cheap just frugal. No need to drive a ground rod.

Comment: An Ufer ground is **far superior** to a driven rod, or two or three driven rods, and costs very little if put in as part of the concrete pour (which is really the only way to put one in) - any good concrete contractor should at minimum ask you, or simply do it (it's actually a legal requirement in some LAHJ that any new footing have the Ufer ground built in.)

Comment: @michaelkaras  ,       thank you archon,as stated it is new construction and I'm doing my best to try and stay up with new codes so the ufer is a given, and I appreciate you, you obviously choose you words beautifully. As for Michael my question had nothing to do with trying to "save " anything. I just was unclear if using a ufer properly eliminated the need for a rod or if both were required.

Comment: @archonOSX. Just wanted to thank you for taking your time to help me both by answering my question and for helping me not feel like well the way that Michael guy was trying to make me feel. His comment came up first and I took it like a insult and started to question myself until I saw your comment. So thank you and have a great day.

Comment: Happy to help bring some clarity. Building Codes are sometimes (almost always actually) confusing documents and even after 30 years I still have lots to  learn, and one of the reasons I  come here. Good luck on your project. 

Answer (score 2):

If the concrete encased electrode is of at least 20' of bare solid copper wire buried within 2" of the ground in the concrete footing/foundation or is connected to a galvanized pipe of the same length, it is considered a sufficient grounding electrode.  As a side the code allows the re-bar that is encased in the foundation/footing if it is all tied together with standard steel tie wire to serve as the electrode. No additional ground is required.  This is how I read the code. It is always wise to check with your local inspector.

Comment: One other requirement: the concrete in the foundation must be in direct contact with the earth (no vapor barriers or capillary breaks between the footing and the soil)

Comment: @PaulLogan thank you , this job is in Lakewood, CA. which is LA county, and the inspector very nicely explained that yes the ufer is vastly superior but in la county they require it to go from panel to ufer to water pipe to ground rod. Reason being such wide diversity of soils having ufer and rod ensures its as close to 20 ohms as possible. Thank you again